# PDFMAKE Watermark for pdf is not being generated

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdfmake

I am trying to generate pdf with watermark using pdfmake.However on using the property "watermark:'test'",the pdf is not being generated.An error pops up on the console saying "Font 'undefined' in style 'normal' is not defined in the font section of the document definition".How to generate PDF's with watermark using PDFMAKE JS library.

```
<html>
        <head>

            <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction()
        {


            var docDefinition = {
                watermark:'test',
      background: 'simple text',
      content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake'

    };
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('Report.pdf');

        }
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in newer versions of pdfMake, make sure you use last version and it will work fine.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var docDefinition = {
    watermark: 'test',
    background: 'simple text',
    content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake'
  };
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('Report.pdf');
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.31/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.31/vfs_fonts.js'></script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```